# Google doc viewer display private documents or python doc rendering library

Tags: security, documentation, viewer

I have a website which in a section gives users access to some documents.
The documents cannot be downloaded from the site, but only if the users are logged in.

Is is possible to use google docs viewer to show a preview of the documents to the user, considering the documents are not downloadable if you aren't logged in ... will the viewer be able to download them in order to render them? As an optional feature, could it use a secure connection when showing the documents?

If this is not possible with google docs viewer, do you know some python library that could render documents as HTML (so that I can return them to the user)? The documents will probably be of various types (like docs, excels, pdf, ppts, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with Google's doc viewer since it needs the URL of the file to be displayed as a parameter (which makes it possible to retrieve the URL and download the documents without being logged in), if want to use it anyway, you'll have to create a *preview* version of your documents.

**Edit :**
You can change the `url` parameter of Google's doc viewer to a script on your server, this script should only accept requests to documents from Google's doc viewer ( identifiable with the user agent `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0,gzip(gfe) (via docs.google.com/viewer)` it's light, I know ) and serve the appropriate file depending on an `id` parameter or something. This way you can control who gets access to the documents. That's my 2 cents.

Comment: It's dubious at best to simply allow only Google to download the file. The person can still modify the src attribute in the Google reader iframe to try and guess which file to download.

Comment: @JohnathanElmore Of course. Security through obscurity is never a good thing.

Comment: You could get the host name from IP, then do a reverse IP address from hostname to better verify the source is google, more info: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80553

Comment: If I understand this correctly its impossible to use the viewer with google's authentication? I keep getting a html file in the viewer when the file isn't publicly shared. But when I share it pulbic it works fine?

Comment: @Nasreddine Would it work to add:
Allow docs.google.com/viewer

To my .htaccess file ?

Comment: Even if you do this, google saves a copy on their servers, which can be downloaded then through the save to my drive or print options if you happen to open the full viewer.

Sorry to bring this up 2 years after, but I'm facing a similar issues and there's no info at all!